# How can I change java version on local linux server

Tags: java, linux, netbeans-8

I built my NetBeans web project with Java 1.5 successfully, however; my linux server supports / uses Java 1.4 and Java 1.5 (as well as JBoss 4.0.2).

When I check the version of my project ( java -version ) it says that the current version is Java  1.4.2. However, I don't want to change the "JAVA_HOME" setting on the server because other projects need to use this version.

I want my project to use Java 1.5 from the server... 
An idea as to how I should go about doing this? Is there a configuration that I can change?

I have this error:

> java.lang.UnsoupportedClassVersionError:  bad Version in .class file

Comment: You should migrate all applications to java 1.7 or higher.

Comment: but other applications isn't mine, some application is on java 1.4 and some is on java 1.5 but java version on server is 1.4.2.. i want simple some config which my war file use java 1.5 on linux server.

Answer (score 1):

You need Java 1.5 version installed in your Linux server.

Next, run the following set of commands in your terminal/command prompt:

- JAVA_HOME="{fix-me}"
- export JAVA_HOME
- export PATH = $JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH

In the place holder {fix-me} specify the path of Java 5 that is installed in the Linux machine.

This would only temporarily set the Java version to 5 until the terminal/command prompt session is alive. So you need not worry about disturbing other projects.

Comment: Way late answer, but good.  Should the OP read this, he/she should also check to see if a CLASSPATH, etc. needs to be set.